# How to combine multiple csv files based on file name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have more than 1000 csv files , i want to combine  where csv filename first five digits are same in to one csv file.

```
    input:
    100044566.csv
    100040457.csv
    100041458.csv
    100034566.csv
    100030457.csv
    100031458.csv
    100031459.csv


import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
path_1 =''
all_files_final = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_1, "*.csv"))
names_1 = [os.path.basename(x1) for x1 in all_files_final]
final = pd.DataFrame()

for file_1, name_1 in zip(all_files_final, names_1):
    file_df_final = pd.read_csv(file_1,index_col=False)
    #file_df['file_name'] = name
    final = final.append(file_df_final)
final.to_csv('',index=False)
```

i used the above code but its merging all files in to one csv file , i dont know have to make selection based on the name

so from above input
output 1: combine first three csv files in one csv file because filename first five digits are same.

output 2: combine next 4 files in one csv files because filename first five digits are same.

Comment: which part are you facing problem in achieving this?

Comment: what you have done so far ? kindly add the code

Comment: code is added that i tried so far

Comment: @ i am facing problem to merging file based on filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to approach the problem slightly differently.

Here's my solution:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir('.') # returns list of filenames in current folder
files_of_interest = {} # a dictionary that we will be using in future

for filename in files: # iterate over files in a folder
    if filename[-4:] == '.csv': # check whether a file is of .csv format
        key = filename[:5] # as you've mentioned in you question - first five characters of filename is of interest
        files_of_interest.setdefault(key,[]) #if we dont have such key - .setdefault will create such key for us and assign empy list to it
        files_of_interest[key].append(filename) # append to a list new filename

for key in files_of_interest: 
    buff_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for filename in files_of_interest[key]:
        buff_df= buff_df.append(pd.read_csv(filename)) # iterate over every filename for specific key in dictionary and appending it to buff_df
    files_of_interest[key]=buff_df # replacing list of files by a data frame
```

This code will create a dictionary of dataframes. Where keys of the dictionary will be a set of first unique characters of *.csv* files.

Then you can iterate over keys of the dictionary to save every according dataframe as a *.csv* file.

Hope my answer helped.